# fail2ban - block from mail.log "SSL_accept error from"

Tags: fail2ban

i would like to block IP address with fail2ban if in postfix mail log is line:

```
SSL_accept error from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: lost connection
```

i try make fail2ban ssl_error.conf in filter.d with this line:

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)sSSL_accept error from \S+\s*\[<HOST>\]: lost connection$
```

but no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `^%(__prefix_line)s` part. Simply set

```
failregex = SSL_accept error from \S+\s*\[<HOST>\]: lost connection
```